# Xcode: the specified item could not be found in the keychain only while PKI key plugged

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, codesign

I got this error when I try to run and install on physical iPhone/iPad device **but only** when I plug my corporate PKI security USB key.

```
...
the specified item could not be found in the keychain.
```

I already run this command to list my code signing identities

```
$ security find-identity -v -p codesigning
```

Everything looks fine and all my certificates are in my keychain.

When I remove the PKI key, the app can be run & install on the physical device.

I don't have any issue running on simulator.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer !

You need to add your developer certificates **inside** your PKI USB Key !

First export your developer certificate

- Open Keychain
- Right click on the iPhone Developer certificate (the one with the key icon)
- Export
- Be sure to check "allow access to all apps" in the second tab

Then inside your PKI USB Key tool, import your certificate. I use **SafeNet** Tools to view my PKI Key.

- Open SafeNet Tools
- Click on settings
- Tokens
- User certificates
- Import your developer certificate

Once certificate is imported, **unplug your PKI USB Key and plug it again** !

Everything should be fine and build successful ✅ !

Comment: Lol I ended here after a weird error - only then I realized I have a PKI USB Key plugged in. Amazing technology :D